# Dismissing using UIModalPresentationStyle.OverFullScreen results in black screen

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view controller (`VCA`) that modally presents another view controller `VCB`:

```
presentViewController(VCB, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

If `VCB` has a `modalPresentationStyle = .OverFullScreen` (same applies for `.OverCurrentContext`), why when it is dismissed:

```
dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

does the following code when the transition is finished result in `VCA` turning black?

```
func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

    let toVC = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextToViewContrllerKey)!
    let fromVc = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey)!
    var containerView = transitionContext.containerView()!

    if presenting {
        toVC.view.alpha = 0
        containerView.insertSubview(toVC.view, aboveSubview: fromVC.view)
    } else {
        containerView.insertSubview(toVC.view, belowSubview: fromVC.view)
    }

    UIView.animateWithDuration(transitionDuration(transitionContext), delay: 0.0, options: [.CurveEaseInOut], animations: {
        if self.presenting {
            self.toVC.view.alpha = 1
        } else {
            self.fromVC.view.alpha = 0
        }
        } , completion: { finished in
            self.transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
    })
}
```

Is there a way to fix this **without** removing the line `containerView.insertSubview(toVC.view, belowSubview: fromVC.view)` **or** checking the value of `fromVC.modalPresentationStyle` before executing the above line? i.e. is there some parameter I can set in `VCA`'s or `VCB`'s initialiser?

Many thanks for any help.